# Hide rows when column values are duplicate

Tags: sql-server, duplicates, hide

I have a table named "`letters`" with two columns looking like this:

```
case_nr | date
--------+-----------------------
1       | 2015-06-13 12:45:04
1       | NULL
2       | 2015-06-11 12:45:09
3       | 2015-06-12 17:41:49
3       | 2015-06-13 18:42:99
```

`case_nr` 1 have printed 2 letters but only one was sent

I want to filter all cases where all letters was sent (have a date)

So in this case result should be:

```
2
3
```

Comment: Are there any indexes on the table? What's the expected data size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `DISTINCT` with `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT case_nr
FROM TableName
WHERE case_nr NOT IN 
          (SELECT case_nr FROM TableName WHERE [date] IS NULL )
```

Result:

```
case_nr
--------
2
3
```

Sample result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9c3f7/2).

Answer (score 2):

Group by the `case_nr` and take only those having no record with `date is null`

```
select case_nr
from your_table
group by case_nr
having sum(case when date is null then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

#### [SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9c3f7/6)

Comment: The CASE statement seems to be missing the alternative, no?

Comment: @bartover: No, the alternative is  automatically `null` then.

Comment: @bartover: I was wrong. Seems like SQL Server needs an alternative to sum correctly. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative:

```
SELECT 
    case_nr
FROM (
    SELECT
        case_nr,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN [date] IS NULL THEN 1 END) AS cnt
    FROM 
        yourTable
    GROUP BY
        case_nr
    ) t
WHERE
    cnt = 0
```